# How to remedy unmet dependencies error while downloading Steam?

Tags: apt, dependencies, steam

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on a new Asus notebook computer (Ubuntu was pre-installed).  I tried to download Steam from the software center and received the following error:

```
Package dependencies cannot be resolved
```

This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

steam-launcher: Depends: curl but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15) but 2.15-0ubuntu10.2 is to be installed
```

Before I tried to download Steam I was successful installing and running minecraft.jar - that is the only other program that I have installed.

I have searched for a solution for this issue on this site but I haven't seen my problem identified exactly and I'm afraid to just keep running other scripts that may cause additional conflicts.  Please help!  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should not download Steam from Software Center. Go to

```
store.steamcommunity.com
```

and download the version from there. It's a .deb package, meaning it will open in Software Center and install there. It never worked for me to download Steam from Software Center :)

Comment: I tried the direct download and it failed also.  I ran a diagnostic from the Terminal as suggested on another post - I'll try to post the results.

Comment: After the edit I can see what is going on. Try `sudo apt-get install curl`

Comment: ran sudo apt-get install curl with the following results: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package curl is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'curl' has no installation candidate

Comment: Can't see the results, pastebin them

Comment: the results wouldn't post because it contained several weblinks and the website wouldn't allow me to post more than two. One error line reads "Err http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found"  How do you pastebin?

Comment: To be clear, the results were generated from running "sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update"

Comment: ehh, dude, just do `sudo apt-get install curl`

Comment: Ran sudo apt-get install pastebinit and received the following results: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

Comment: cont'd. The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 pastebinit : Depends: python-configobj but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt-get install curl` ?

Comment: Xylo, I ran sudo apt-get install curl. It didn't work. Results =  Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree Reading state information... Done Package curl is not available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source E: Package 'curl' has no installation candidate